# Find the element before the previous element - jQuery

Tags: javascript

I need to select the element 2 up from my current element. Normally you can use the .prev() to find the previous element but I need to find the one previous to this. Whats the simplest way to find this?

```
var animation = $("div.services-block").prev();
```

I need to find the div before services-block and load that into a variable.

My structure as an example

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="services-block-item"></div>
<div class="services-block-item-match"></div>
<div class="services-block-item"></div>
<div class="services-block"></div>
</div>
```

Say my current element is services-block, I need to find and grab services-block-item-match. (but this class name can change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "this current element" changes, some code like the following might be useful:

I used a different example: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/5/ to illustrate the ability of $(this) with the .prev().prev() that may be helpful for your problem.

```
$(this).prev().prev().css('color', 'red');
```

In this fiddle illustration, a link is clicked and then jquery changes the element that is 2 spots ahead of it to have red colored text.  There are four links, so if you click 4, link 2 will be red, if you click 3, link 1 would be highlighted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var animation = $(".services-block").prev().prev();
```

Comment: What's the difference you'll get by removing the `div` from the selector, apart from making it less specific?

Comment: @MelanciaUK, Does the use of div makes it run faster, should i always give tag with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.
How does this work exactly?